# Is it possible to dissect a regular polygon into mirrored-symmetric pieces?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polygons

Q1. Planar regular triangle is dissected into three congruent pieces, each of them having no symmetry axis.
Can it be so, that one of these pieces is a mirrored (and then rotated) copy of some other of these pieces?
(There is no limitations, whether the pieces are convex, singly connected etc.)

Q2. The similar question about the regular n-gon and n congruent pieces, where n is a prime number.

[image]

The picture  shows an example for n = 6 to clarify the task. 
A blue piece is a rotated copy of the green piece, and no mirroring is required. But a green piece can be obtained from the yellow piece only involving the mirroring (and then, probably, some rotation).
But n = 6 is not a prime number, while Q2 is about the prime n.

Comment: When you say “congruent pieces”, do you actually mean “pieces of equal area”?  Or when you say “copy of”, are you actually excluding translated copies?  If two pieces are congruent then mirroring, rotation and translation is enough to map one to the other.

Comment: non clear if each piece must be a rotated-translated-possibly mirrored copy of *each other*, or just of *some other*

Comment: To understand, what does "congruent pieces" mean, please look
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)
Obviously, congruent pieces have equal areas.
I would like to find such three pieces P1, P2 and P3 of a regular triangle, that P1 is congruent to P2, P1 is congruent to P3 (hence P2 is congruent to P3), and P2 is a rotated (and, probably, then translated) copy of P1 (**without mirroring**), and P3 is obtained from P1 **using mirroring** and rotation (and, probably, then translation).